# How to build Java from WSDL that uses existing XSD types

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl

I'm trying to create a new web service that uses existing types.  The types are defined in an existing XSD that we received, along with a matching JAR file, from a third party.  If I just import that XSD into my WSDL and build the Java (using wsconsume), then all the existing types are also built.  Since we already have a JAR that contains all these Java types, we don't want to generate them again.

As a fallback option I can have ant delete these redundant files, but I'd rather find a way to not generate them in the first place.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [Spring WebServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/) which should help you with such implementation, it:

- has a principle of *contract first* where the contract is rather XSD than WSDL
- allows you to write `@Endpoint` class with methods annotated with e.g. `@PayloadRoot` and using parameters of types from the JAR you've got
- allows you to generate WSDL with `<sws:dynamic-wsdl />`

If the JAR you've got has classes with JAXB annotations then you can use JAXB directly, if not - you can alway use other binding technologies.

Comment: Unfortunately our framework is set, and does not include Spring.  Can you give any more explanation of how to "use JAXB directly"?

Comment: What's your framework? By *JAXB directly* I mean using Spring-WS which allows using JAXB classes as method parameter in **your own classes** thus freeing you from generating any code but domain classes.

Comment: It turns out I'll not be doing this right now anyway - so thanks for your advice.  We're using JBoss 4.2.3 as the server & app container.  Will what you're suggesting work with that?